# Changing the culture causing exception

Tags: wpf, localization

I've tried to change the culture to es-es in the code behind of the main window

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-es");
        }
```

and got this error :

> Cannot locate resource 'panelview.baml'.

while panelview is a user control that i'm using in the main window.
Can someone guess what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

Answer (score 0):

Did you the `NeutralResourcesLanguage` attribute in your AssemblyInfo, similar to this?

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

If yes, try removing that line and see if that works.

Had a similar issue where the application would search for an satellite assembly that wasn't there. 
Another way to fix this could be to have an resource file for es-ES.

Comment: Thanks but i don't have this line in my assembly info, now i've tried to add it but it did nothing.
I have a resource files called Strings.es-ES.resx and Strings.resx

Answer (score 0):

Try calling another page from MainWindow and see if changes would appear in that page. MainWindow won't reflect.